# Constructor Chaining in Java

Tags: java, constructor

When creating multiple constructors, I usually do the following;

```
public ConstructorName(int count)
{
    this(count, 0);
}

public ConstructorName(String count)
{
    this(Integer.parseInt(count), 0);
}

public ConstructorName(int count, int other)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

However, I can also do it this way;

```
public ConstructorName(String count)
{
    this(Integer.parseInt(count)); // Chain to the constructor that just takes a number
}

public ConstructorName(int count)
{
    this(count, 0);
}

public ConstructorName(int count, int other)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

Is there any actual difference here? Which would be better to use when coding?

Comment: The first option will be slightly more efficient. Less switching scopes = less time wasted unnecessarily popping stuff on and off the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't answer the question directly, but its far more better *not* to overload constructors/function

Instead of constructor overloading you should make the construtor private and call it from public static functions which do start with "create" or something like that.

For example:

```
class ClassName
{
    static public ClassName createFromCountString(string count)
    {
        return new ClassName(Integer.parseInt(count), 0);
    }

    static public ClassName createFromCount(int count)
    {
        return new ClassName(count, 0);
    }

    static public ClassName createFromCountAndOther(int count, int other)
    {
        return new ClassName(count, other);
    }

    private ClassName(int count, int other)
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you write `this()` outside a constructor?

Comment: @tintinmj the methods all belong to the ClassName class

Comment: @Quonux first of all you can't use `this` inside static method. Second you can call a constructor **ONLY** inside from another constructor.

Comment: @tintinmj ok i corrected it, and you can't call it this way in *java*, but its possible in *d*, but it wasn't real java so i changed it

Comment: @tintinmj calling the constructor outside of a static function works http://ideone.com/Wawrd1

Comment: @Quonux did you use `this`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9883/discussion-between-tintinmj-and-quonux)

Comment: Why is it better?

Comment: @PeterTaylor it is more readable

Answer (score 2):

If there is more than one way to construct an instance, then *static factory methods* backed by one private constructor, can really help readability, since they can be named differently.

```
Range halfOpen = Range.largerThan(5);
Range closed = Range.between(7, 12);
```

If it is really about setting some properties and not others, then the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) can be what you want.

```
Person john = Person.named("John")
    .lastName("Lennon")
    .gender(Male)
    .yearOfBirth(1940)
    .build();
```

Both of these approaches also allow for hiding which implementation class is really returned. Our `Person` instance may be an instance of subclass `Man`, and the half open `Range` may be an instance of `HalfOpenRange`. Both methods allow returning a cached instance, rather than an actual new instance.